# Deploy nested resources separately

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory

Due to separation of duty I need to split an existing ARM template into two single templates - one for the resource and one for the logging

the original templates looks like this:

```
"resources": [
{ // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories
  "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
  "name": "[variables('dataFactoryName')]",
  "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {},
  "identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
  },
  "properties": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "providers/diagnosticSettings",
      "name": "[concat('Microsoft.Insights/', variables('logSettingName'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', variables('dataFactoryName'))]"
      ],
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {},
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('logSettingName')]",

        "workspaceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('logAnalyticsObject').resourceGroup, '//providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('logAnalyticsObject').name)]",

        "logs": "[parameters('logAnalyticsObject').adfv2.logs]",
        "metrics": "[parameters('logAnalyticsObject').adfv2.metrics]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The first part is quite easy, I just remove the sub-resource but how to get the second part (resource with "type": "providers/diagnosticSettings") correctly so it can be deployed from a different template?
Is this possible at all or are these strongly tied together?

I already tried different things like

```
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/providers/diagnosticSettings",
"name": "[concat('Microsoft.Insights/', variables('name'))]",
```

but ended up with error messages like this:

```
Unable to process template language expressions for resource '/subscriptions/fb1e20c4-0878-4949-ac10-f92a9ac35db4/resourceGroups/swe-sdp-dv0
-rgp-adp/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/DataFactory_LogAnalytics_Resource' at line '67' and column '5'. 'Unable to evaluate template language 
function 'resourceId': function requires exactly one multi-segmented argument which must be resource type including resource provider namespace. Current 
function arguments 'fb1e20c4-0878-4949-ac10-f92a9ac35db4,swe-sdp-dv0-rgp-anl,Microsoft.Insights,swe-sdp-dv0-oms-001'. Please see 
https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions/#resourceid for usage details.
```

I think to make it work I would need the right combination of "type", "name" and probably also "dependsOn"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#set-up-diagnostic-logs), you would need to do this:

```
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/providers/diagnosticSettings",
"name": "[concat(variables('dataFactoryName'), '/Microsoft.Insights/', variables('name'))]",
```

you dont need dependsOn, because resources are under different templates.

Comment: this gives me the error "Server Error 404 - The resource you are looking for 
might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: updated the answer. this is somewhat unusual request path

Comment: just came up with the same about 10 minutes after your answer :)